# Не могу удалить фото из галлереи

Tags: java, android

Не могу удалить фото, зная путь к файлу `file.delete()` - возвращает всегда false.
Не работают и эти методы

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(new File("PATH")))); 

getContentResolver().delete(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA + "=?" , new String[]{"PATH"});
```

Разрешения в manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" />
```

Нужно обеспечить работу в Android 5+ (API21+)